# powershell script to mail enable users from CSV

Tags: scripting, powershell

i have the script as

```
5..12 | foreach-object { import-csv "\\servername\staffdata\IT\Login Accounts\2011\AD\Year$_.csv" } | ForEach-Object { Enable-Mailbox $_.email -Database "Student Mailbox Store" }
```

and i have a csv named Year5_2.csv
in the correct folder. 
I am getting the following error

Import-Csv : Cannot open file "\servername\staffdata\IT\Login Accounts\2011\AD\Year5.csv".
At line:1 char:36

Any suggestions please

Comment: disregard i was using the wrong file.

Answer (score 1):

If the file name is Year5_2.csv than you should use syntax similar to:
Import-Csv "\servername\staffdata\IT\Login Accounts\2011\AD\Year$_`_2.csv"

$_ = 5..12
if 2 is also variable than you need to tweak it a bit.
HTH
Bartek